# How can i write a decorator using a class's __call__ function?

Tags: python, django, decorator, python-decorators

The following is my code. Given any content, it has to append certain HTML tag to the content at the front.
I'm learning to write decorators using **call** instead of function closures.

```
class decorate:
    def __init__(self, tag=""):
        self.tag = tag
    def __call__(self, function, *args):
        return "<p>{}</p>".format(self.tag, function(*args), self.tag)

@decorate(tag="p")
def get_content(content):
    return content    

print(get_content("I'm awesome"))

# Error i got.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cache.py", line 27, in <module>
    @decorate(tag="p")
  File "cache.py", line 25, in __call__
    return "<p>{}</p>".format(self.tag, function(*args), self.tag)
TypeError: get_content() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
def __call__(self, function, *args):
    return "<p>{}</p>".format(self.tag, function(*args), self.tag)
```

into:

```
def __call__(self, function):
   def wrap(*args):
       return "<{}>{}</{}>".format(self.tag, function(*args), self.tag)
   return wrap
```

You may want to look into `functools` for more refined decoration of `wrap`, but except for supporting `help` and the like, this should work.

Comment: yes. This worked. But now i'm trying to implement a cache using decorator and it's getting similar error. 
Code: http://ideone.com/kUu9XH

Comment: @user1159517, per StackOverlow's etiquette, please post that as a separate question including the code that's giving you problems (links to offsite places of that code not welcome), exactly what you expected, exactly what you observed, and so forth.